# What is causing this Google Maps marker click error in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

[This](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/allmyfinds.html) page allows users to filter (via checkboxes), markers which are placed on the map. Clicking on any marker performs a 'reverse geocode' action and in conjunction with selecting the 'Search Locations' button, the user can then see POI's within a given radius of the clicked marker.

For demo purposes, if you select the 'Coin' checkbox, click the green marker, then select the 'Search Locations' button, the marker will bounce and the right hand sidebar will be populated with POI's.

The problem I'm having is that in Internet Explorer everything works fine, but when I try to run this in Chrome, the marker looses the 'bounce' functionality, the 'reverse geocode' doesn't run and in the error console I receive the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: reversegeocode is not defined` at line 55 of my code which is:
`reversegeocode();` I've done some reading on this and other sites and from reading the guidance I've tried changing this part of my code to this:

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
    var clickListener =
    document.getElementById('findosgb36lat').value = this.mylat;
    document.getElementById('findosgb36lon').value = this.mylon;
    document.getElementById('address').value = this.myaddress;
    if(bouncingMarker) 
        bouncingMarker.setAnimation(null); 
        if(bouncingMarker != this) { 
            this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); 
            bouncingMarker = this; 
        }
        else bouncingMarker = null; 
    }

    geocoder.geocode({latLng: pos }, function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
            updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
            updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
    });
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('address').value = str;
}

function getAddress(latlng) {
    if (!geocoder) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            // Looping through the result
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[0].formatted_address) {
                    document.getElementById('address').value = 
                        results[0].formatted_address;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
)
}
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work and actually creates more problems with syntax errors.

I'm relatively new to Javascript, so perhaps I've totally misunderstood,. But I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Code feedback:

- What is the second line in your code: `var clickListener =` meant to do (something is missing)?
- Both of your calls to `geocoder.geocode` pass an object with a property named: `latLng`; the object passed should match the structure of `google.maps.GeocoderRequest`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest), which has properties named: `address`, `bounds`, `location`, and `region`. I suggest you change the name of these properties from: `latLng` to `location`.
- I'm not sure of the context of the code shown, but the usage of `this` in this code section looks suspicious:

```
    if(bouncingMarker != this) { 
        this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); 
        bouncingMarker = this; 
    }
```

It looks like you are within a global function, so it looks like the use of `this` may not make sense here?

That's all I see after a first pass; hope this helps you -

Comment: Hi @Sean Mickey, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. The `var clickListener` is used when the marker or associated sidebar entry is clicked. it's this action that starts the marker bouncing and the 'reverse geocode' action. With respect to the `this`, I'm using it to pull together the lat, lng and address values when the marker is clicked. I hope this makes sense. Kind regards